# What is the generic name for a device that acts as a DisplayPort MST matrix?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, mst

I'm not sure if this is off-topic, as it is about some electronic device, but totally related to computers, so let me know if it is so I delete it without bothering people. Keep in mind I'm NOT asking for specific product recommendations

I currently have a 4x2 HDMI matrix connected to my 2 monitors, and 4 inputs to my computers (2 to each computer, to have the ability to pass any input to any output, using a couple switching buttons). I was given a laptop at work I'm forced to work with from home, and it has only a single DP output. It supports MST, so I bought a MST hub, a couple DP to HDMI conversors, connected them to my cheap matrix, and it kind of works (with minor bearable occasional glitches).

I've chosen this option because I was in a real rush and could not find a matrix like mine, but with DisplayPort, that supported MST in inputs, so I could get the same functinality I've now (redirecting any input, being able to difference from diferent inputs from the same DP cable), but without using that much devices and converters, that add some unwanted clutter to my desk/wall. What is the name of this device, if it exists? Also, what is the normal price range? HDMI 4x2 matrix start as cheap as 60 $ or so, but a MST matrix seems WAY more complicated internally, so I don't know if there's even a market niche for that, specially when you can attach a DP hub to a normal matrix...

Also, I'd like to know what are the "best practises" in order to achieve the functinality I want, just in case I'm absolutly wrong in my approach

**TL;DR Does a display port matrix with multiple inputs and multiple outputs that allows me to set any number of outputs to any number of inputs (respecting bandwidth), but if n inputs are ser to a single input, make use of the MST capabilities of that input exists? If so, what's the generic name so I can look for it? Also, I would like to know the "recommended way" to obtain what I want, if this imaginary device is not or does not exist**

Please, note that I'm not asking for recomendations on SPECIFIC products, but for the generic name of the product so I can search for it, or for a "it doesn't exist" answer

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I would have gotten a DisplayPort to HDMI MST hub instead of a separate hub and converters. Here's one I own by [Club 3D](https://www.amazon.com/Club3D-DisplayPort-HDMI-Multi-Display-CSV-5300H/dp/B00O5M2WDW/). Not saying to specifically buy that one, but daisy chaining several adapters together builds resistance and can throttle throughput.  It's better if you can do it all in one device. DisplayPort is a persnickety connection type.  The only DP switches I've ever seen are single output (or parallel double on DP KVMs), never a matrix though.

Comment: @Blaelph havent found a matrix yet, so I'll have to assume you're correct, but I came across the specific porduct you listed, but according to it's spects, it cannot handle 3x monitors which are all higher than FHD with a high refresh rate, am I right? I'm thinking about following your advice and getting the 2x hdmi output equivalent to the one you showed, but from startech (same brand than the one I own now that outputs 2 DP). It's USB powered and seems to have a it higher total throughput. I guess I won't be able to get rid of HDMI this decade :(.